# Is it possible to prove from relativity that massless things have proper time of zero?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, speed-of-light

Is it possible to come to the conclusion that something massless has proper time of zero, thus moves at $c$? I have seen many arguments for why moving at the speed of light means proper time is zero, but I want to start purely with the metric and/or principles of relativity to come to this conclusion.

I have tried some approaches involving equations of motion, but the Christoffel symbols are all zero, so that wasn't fruitful. That's the only way I know to relate mass to motion at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to answer this question in special relativity. The generalisation to general relativity is obvious. So let's do it in SR. The trajectory of relativistic free particles, in Hamiltonian mechanics, is given by:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{pc^2}{\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}}$$

To have $\frac{dx}{dt}=c$, you need $m=0$. A speed of $c$ also implies null intervals, as you already know.

Generalisation to general relativity: In general relativity, special relativity is locally obeyed at every point. So, for each tiny piece of the massless particle trajectory, you have $g_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}=0$. You can switch to locally inertial co-ordinates to show this. The total proper time is the sum of the proper times of each piece, so it is also zero.

Technically, light is a wave. So we should really derive $E=pc$ using the wave-equation. And then we should talk about a massless particle trajectory only in the geometric optics limit.

Answer (score 0):

The change in proper time between two points $A$ and $B$ on a timelike geodesic separated by a small amount is **defined** by (the square root of minus one times) the spacetime interval between those points:
\begin{equation}
\Delta \tau \equiv \sqrt{- \Delta s^2}
\end{equation}
(where I am using the "mostly plus" metric convention).

Massless particles follow null geodesics. **By definition**, the spacetime interval between two points $A$ and $B$ separated by a small amount on a null geodesic *is zero*, $\Delta s^2=0$.

If you insist on assigning a proper time to a null geodesic, then the only choice consistent with the above statements is to say that the proper time is constant at all points along a null geodesic: $\Delta \tau = \sqrt{-\Delta s^2} = 0$.

In fact, I would prefer to say that proper time as a concept only makes sense for timelike geodesics, and does not make sense for null geodesics. Instead, to parameterize a null geodesic, we should use an *affine parameter* in order to simplify the form of the geodesic equation.

Comment: i feel like this dances around the question. "Massless particles follow null geodesics" is, I think, what I am looking to be explained/proven.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate on "Massless particles follow null geodesics. By definition, the spacetime interval between two points  and  separated by a small amount is zero, $\Delta s^2=0$."

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber (1) Null geodesics are *by definition* curves for which $\Delta s^2=0$ between two points on the curve separated by a small amount. (2) One way to see that massless particles follow null geodesics is to start from the relativistic generalization of $E=mc^2$, namely $p_\mu p^\mu = -m^2$, where $p_\mu p^\mu = -E^2 + \vec{p}^2$, and where $p^\mu$ is the *4-momentum* of the particle. When $m^2=0$, $p^\mu$ is a null vector (since its norm is zero). Since the 4-momentum is tangent to the curve the particle follows, a massless particle follows a null curve.

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber I gave a more physics-y type argument for why massless particles travel at $c$ here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651784/can-massless-particles-travel-slower-than-the-speed-of-light-in-vacuum/651787#651787. Once you know they travel at $c$, it immediately follows that they travel on null geodesics, since $$\Delta s^2=0 \implies \frac{|\Delta \vec{x}|}{\Delta t} \equiv |\vec{v}| = c$$.

Answer (score 0):

In relativistic theory, we call proper time τ of an object the time measured in “the” reference frame of this object, that is to say in a reference frame where it is immobile.

The photon (m=0) has no reference frame where it is at rest, so the proposition '' is that it has zero "proper" time is "undecidable" in the special theory of relativity.